# Differential equation first order and Appell polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to obtain a primitive function for following differential equation
$$h'(x)=\sum_n^\infty \frac{P_{n}'(x)}{n!}t^n = \sum_n^\infty \frac{nP_{n-1}(x)}{n!}t^n $$
This is the first order differential equation and i know that solution is $A(t)e^{xt}$, where $A(t)$ is generating function. $P_n(x)$ are Appell polynomials.

My attempt:
$$h'(x)=\sum_n^\infty \frac{P_{n}'(x)}{n!}t^n = \sum_n^\infty \frac{nP_{n-1}(x)}{n!}t^n = \sum_n^\infty \frac{P_{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!}t^n. $$

We know that for Appell polynomials holds following relations:
$P_n'(x)=nP_{n-1}(x)$. Now we need to just integrate both sides of the equation and we have $$h(x)=\sum_n^\infty \frac{P_{n}(x)}{n!}t^n$$ So actually this is what we wanted.

Comment: A second thought:  $h'(x)=\sum_n^\infty \frac{P_{n}'(x)}{n!}t^n$ implies **directly** $h(x)=\sum_n^\infty \frac{P_{n}(x)}{n!}t^n$ + constant, isn't it ? But then, where is the problem ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I know that we need to push the limits of aggregation, because if we differentiate the function $h(x)$ and then integrate it, unfortunately, it doesn't prove anything.